# Need C# client to connect to server with low latency bi-direction communication

Tags: c#

I'm in the process of learning C# and just need a pointing in the right direction. I want to build a client in C# that communicates with a server running PHP/mySQL. There will need to be almost constant communication between the two. It will be for a game, so low-latency and bi-directional communication. I'm not looking for an exact how-to, but rather what method I need to use to connect the two for the fastest and most reliable connection. I have read others use XML, but that seems like it would be slower if used near-constantly, like once or more a second, but I could be totally wrong. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Normally communication with those characteristics is made over a persistent TCP connection. C# offers lots of ready-to-use functionality in the [`System.Net.Sockets`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb27wehh.aspx) namespace (start looking from [`TcpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) and [`TcpListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx); there are also more low-level interfaces if you need them).

The important question here is: what do you mean exactly "server running PHP"? If the server offers only an HTTP interface, then you would find it more natural to communicate not with sockets but with the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) or the more low-level [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) classes instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Well I am proficient in PHP, so thats what I made my game in. Right now I have a browser-based "client" built with Javascript that uses AJAX to communicate with the server. It's not perfect, but it works (most of the time). I have some issues when commands are sent too quickly. But I want to build a client in C# for 2 reasons: to be able to customize and completely control what happens in the client, and better my resume by learning an desktop application-development language like C#.

Comment: Actually no, such communication is normally NOT done with TCP connections but with UDP as prety much every hjigh quality financial low latency data feed demonstrates, as well as every standard for video or pure audio conferencing. TCP has serious problems quaranteeing low latency when packet loss hits.

Comment: @TomTom: If you need guaranteed delivery then it's TCP. If you don't, then UDP is definitely a prime candidate -- after reading the question, I am assuming that the OP has not made a deliberate decision between the two and should therefore be directed to the "if you don't *know* that you need something different, use this" solution (TCP).

Comment: Crap. If you need fast guaranteed delivers go with UDB and implement your own protocol on top - like for example NANEX does with their financial data stream (happy customer here). TCP can take a couple of minutes (!) to recover a lost packet, and all the while your whole stream stops. TCP is reliable, but it is not even remotely handled to handle packet loss decently.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, writing a game in C# as a means to get started with the language! How many have started this way.

Have you defined your client-server protocol yet? I'm not talking about TCP vs. UDP, which TomTom and Jon have discussed. I mean, what is the data stream going to look like?

Packet fragmentation is the enemy of low-latency network code. Learn about MTU and packet fragmentation, Nagle's algorithm, etc. and write down some notes for later when you implement the network code. Make sure you calculate the smallest size packet you would be interested in sending, how big its headers might be, and how large of a payload you can fit into that packet. Then see if you can come up with a protocol that uses the available space efficiently.

You may gain a lot more by optimizing your server application and/or porting it to a different language. Just because you CAN use PHP for everything server side doesn't mean you SHOULD. Keep the part that shows you useful information in a web browser, and evaluate whether you should rewrite the time-critical and game client communication parts in another language. Interpreted languages are not especially well known for their speed when crunching real-time game world data. Sure, I once wrote something like that in Perl using POE, but ultimately it was a lot less performant than the C code I was mimicking.

Finally, I would recommend you look into XNA, since it has a lot of this stuff already.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. You have given me a lot of stuff to research! I haven't defined a client-server protocol yet. I am really just getting started on the client-side.